# OS Command Injection Security Threat

Tags: java, security, runtime.exec

We are using command injection concept by using the following code,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

but a system identified this as security threat, so can someone suggest any other way or any third party API is available for doing this command injection. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: As soon as you execute a System command, the threat is here. Whatever the API you use

Comment: I have read in Owasp wiki that the command injection is always a security threat. For reference see [Command injection in Java](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_injection_in_Java)

Comment: This question might be too broad to answer, because there is just too less context given.

Comment: So, there is no other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I strongly suggest avoiding putting untrusted input on the command line. Or at the very least Base64 encode it. Doesn't help with running third-party binaries. / Note also that the Java exec APIs are loosely specified.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use ProcessBuilder, this class is used to create operating system processes, Because Developers should avoid invoking the shell using Runtime.exec in order to call operating system specific commands and should use Java APIs instead.

Each ProcessBuilder instance manages a collection of process attributes. The start() method creates a new Process instance with those attributes. The start() method can be invoked repeatedly from the same instance to create new subprocesses with identical or related attributes.

Starting a new process which uses the default working directory and environment is easy:

```
 Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
```

Here is an example that starts a process with a modified working directory and environment, and redirects standard output and error to be appended to a log file:

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 File log = new File("log");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
 Process p = pb.start();
 assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
 assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
 assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

Remember it is supported from java 5 onwards and Class is not synchronized.

Check Links--

[Source Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

[Code Samples](https://blog.art-of-coding.eu/executing-operating-system-commands-from-java/)

Comment: Even using the ProcessBuilder doesn't help. Veracode still flags it as Very High security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/enhancements.html).

For more details on reducing the threats, refer the guidelines provided [here](http://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/2014/10/3/a-java-web-apps-attack-surface-to-shellshock.html).